# Ad Mob says that my app contains "Derogatory or dangerous content" and has layout problems after months of no problems

Tags: swiftui, admob

I have been using Google Ad Mob for almost three months without any problem, and then all of a sudden my app gets suspended because Google Ad Mob says that my app has the following problems:

- Derogatory or Dangerous Content
- Encouraging Unintentional Clicks
- Content that obscures the ads served by Google

The second and the third one I do not understand how I can have no problem for three months, and then receive this layout problem without having changed anything as far as item positioning is concerned. But the thing that I cannot understand in any way is the first one.
[My app](https://apps.apple.com/app/how-rich-are-the-richest/id1586855133) is a little game in which you choose a billionaire, and you try to spend all of his money within this fake e-commerce. It's a way to get a grasp and understand how much "hundreds of billions of dollars" actually are. So I truly don't understand where the derogatory or dangerous content might be.
The ads are on top of the ContentView as such:

```
struct ContentView : View { 
 var body : some View {
   ZStack {
   VStack {
     // Elements
     }
    VStack {
    Spacer()
    AdView()
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

For months this exact code has been working fine, and suddenly I received those warnings in my Google Ad Mob profile. What might be the reason for this?
I tried writing on the community section within Google Ad Mob, but I only receive replies that link me to the same pages I see within my Ad Mob profile, without any explanation. And I cannot contact them via email, because when I fill in the information in the contact section, the only option that is available for me is “community”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - SOLVED: I have uploaded a new version of the app in which I changed nothing, just the build and the version numbers, asked Google to check my new submission, and everything was fine. I received an email saying that they checked my app and saying "We have reviewed your app and found no policy violations". I still have no idea why that happened, since I changed nothing in the new version.